# Rotation Of An Image In JLabel - Java

Tags: java, eclipse, image, jlabel, image-rotation

I am currently making a game with Java. I added an image to the screen using a `JLabel` and I want to know how to rotate it. I have done a lot of research but have not found anything useful. Can I have some help? Here is my code:

(Code from first class)

```
public static ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("Images/unnamed.png");
public static JLabel label = new JLabel("", image, JLabel.CENTER);
```

(Code from second class)

```
Main.label.setBounds(Game.birdX, Game.birdY, Game.birdWidth, Game.birdWidth);
add(Main.label);
```

Sorry if I am doing something wrong on this website, it's one of my first times using it. Also, I have only been coding Java for 2 weeks now.

Comment: Take a look at this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43958482/how-do-i-align-components-in-java-swing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to use the [Rotated Icon](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/04/06/rotated-icon/).

You just specify the degrees of rotation and a new Icon will be created for you.

Also, don't use static variable. This suggests improper design. The icon and label should just be instance variables in the class where you use them.

Comment: I read the tutorial on the RotatedIcon and created a class for it. I still find it a bit confusing though. How would I make a new RotatedIcon that rotates the image to a specific degree? Thanks.

Comment: Yeah I saw it I just used it the wrong way. I just figured out my mistake a couple minutes ago. Thanks anyways.